# Ansible Tower CLI pass Launch Parameters in one command without prompt

Tags: jenkins, ansible, ansible-tower

I am trying to launch an ansible-tower cli job through Jenkins. But I don't want a prompt that appears on Ansible Tower. I want to pass those parameters in the same command so that a prompt is not required.

I have tried:

```
tower-cli job launch --job-template=33 -e "param1" -e "param2"
```

This is the error I get:

> Error: failed to pass some of the extra variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Ansible Tower-CLI [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/3.5.3/html/towerapi/tower_cli.html) the parameter `-e` is wrong. You need to use `--extra-vars`. This differs from ansible-playbook command. So an easy example is

```
tower-cli job launch --job-template 1 --extra-vars '{"x":"y"}'
```

Be aware that you write all vars in one argument. The `--extra-vars` expects JSON or YAML format.

Be also aware, that the given job template MUST be configured to ask for extra-vars. Otherwise the argument is ignored on Ansible Tower side.

Also - not the question but a good advice - if your Jenkins needs to wait for the job result add `--monitor` to the tower-cli command. Then the cli waits for the response code and the stage could "fail" if there is a problem.